# Determine what error assert_not clause passes with in a Rails 4 test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I test if my object fails validation using `assert_not`, so it actually passes on failed validations. However, I want to know which validations it fails on specifically.

**Essentially, how do I make sure that my object at least fails `validates_acceptance_of :terms` in my case?**

```
class StaffTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  context "Save staff and validate" do
    setup do
      @staff = Fabricate.build(:staff)
      @new_staff = Staff.new
    end

    teardown do 
      @staff = nil
      @new_staff = nil
    end

    should "fail if save without accepting terms" do
      @staff.validate_terms = true
      assert_not @staff.valid?, @staff.errors.full_messages.inspect
    end
  end
end
```

Supposedly, I want my test to pass because it fails password validation. In reality, however, it did pass, but it passed because it failed on terms acceptance validation. In this case, my test did not serve it purpose. Therefore, I want to make sure that the test passes on the correct failure.

I am using Rails 4, Shoulda and ActiveSupport::TestCase (Minitest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@staff.errors.messages will contain hash of each error field name and corresponding message. you can use this for this purpose.

```
assert !@staff.save
assert @staff.errors.messages.values.include?("msg must be there")
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in one line? or a block

Comment: yes you can use assert_raise and call .save! which should raise an exception. you can also add exception type in assert_raise for more please see documentation http://apidock.com/ruby/Test/Unit/Assertions/assert_raise